# Can Cordova open iOS system window without an address bar?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I use this line to open a system browser with `location=no` option:

```
window.open("https://...", "_system", "EnableViewPortScale=yes,hidden=no,toolbar=no,location=no");
```

But the address bar is still there.

Is `location=no` working for system browser on iOS or only for the other types of browsers (like blank)?

Comment: _system opens the web browser you have installed, you can't control any of it from your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those options only work for the InAppBrowser when used with `_blank`, not `_system`.